# How to make Postfix hand off emails via LMTP to Dovecot better (virtual vs relay)?

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

There are 2 ways how `Postfix` can hand off emails via `LMTP`.

**The first approach** is recommended by Kyle Dent in his book about Postfix. He suggests it in cases when we want to store emails in a proprietary message store which is not supported by Postfix (like `mdbox`).

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_recipients
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/imap/socket/lmtp
```

`/etc/postfix/virtual_domains`:

```
a.com -
b.com -
```

`/etc/postfix/virtual_recipients`:

```
z@a.com -
z@b.com -
```

**The second approach** is recommended by Peer Heinlein, the author of the book about Dovecot. He says that it's much better to make Postfix a relay.

```
relay_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
relay_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

`/etc/postfix/transport`:

```
a.com lmtp:unix:/var/imap/socket/lmtp
b.com lmtp:unix:/var/imap/socket/lmtp
```

`/etc/postfix/relay_recipients`:

```
z@a.com -
z@b.com -
```

He doesn't recommend the first approach because:

- "Postfix logic dictates that email domains and host names should be entered there only if Postfix itself is the final physical destination of the routing of the email" [but in the first case postfix hands off emails to dovecot instead of storing them by itself]
- In the case, when Dovecot users are stored in the database, "Postfix has nothing to do with the user data" [in `virtual_mailbox_domains` and `virtual_mailbox_maps` we can use the same external database to refuse emails for unknown recipients]
- "root@localhost and wwwrun@localhost is also delivered to Dovecot via LMTP - and these important system accounts are often not even set up" [is it possible to use the local transport to such emails and for the rest use virtual transport to hand off emails to dovecot via LMTP?]

I like the first approach and don't see any valuable advantages to use the second one yet. When we need to send emails to different MTA, then we should make Postfix as a relay. But maybe I'm wrong, so I decided to ask about it here.

Both cases send email to the queue, both filter emails sent to non-existent recipients so they don't even get into the queue. So what's the real difference between these 2 ways and what advantages and disadvantages each of them?

Comment: Look at which software versions each of these were written for. Some of the recommendations around what makes a good setup assume *since properly resolved* concerns about verifying non-existing addresses, or compare LMTP-transports with non-LMTP transports (delivery via command `lda`), or worry about how one could work around historic limitations for the case where Postfix and Dovecot are running in separate locations with plausibly flaky connection. - *Consider your use case. Are they on the same machine, then the discussion of what is a "final" destination may be purely academic.*

Comment: Practical example: Send messages to your setup, requesting DSN (`NOTIFY=SUCCESS,FAILURE`), try both valid and invalid addresses. Look at what you get back. If its too much trouble to get these to reveal the amount of information you meant to reveal, you may already have your answer on what degree of *finality* you want to Postfix to assert on receipt.

Comment: Seems that there is only the difference which delivery agent sends a message via LMTP: in the first case it's `virtual`, in the second one - `smtp`. So, in practice, it probably does not really matter. But logically, if the postfix is not a final destination (doesn't store emails by itself, even if the dovecot is placed on the same machine), it makes sense to use relay, instead of virtual.